# Javascript won't stop php form submission

Tags: javascript

Javascript gives error window, but it won't stop the form submission.  I'm stumped at this point and can't find an exact answer.  Here is the code, thanks:

```
    function newNameValidate() {
        var x = document.forms["checkIn"]["newName"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Tech name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

`<form name="checkIn" onsubmit="newNameValidate(checkIn)" action="check_in_complete.php" method="POST">`

`<input type ="submit" class="input" value="CHECK IN">`

Comment: Try adding `return` in the onsubmit.Like this: `onsubmit="return newNameValidate()"`.
Does `x` have a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return the value of the function, onclick="return foo();"

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to return the value returned from the function, but a better option is to use unobtrusive JavaScript:

```
<form name="checkIn" action="check_in_complete.php" method="POST">
```

Script:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.forms["checkIn"].onsubmit = newNameValidate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be done like: 
<form name="checkIn" id="checkIn" action="check_in_complete.php" method="POST">
<input type ="button" class="input" value="CHECK IN"  onclick="newNameValidate()">
</form>

<script>
function newNameValidate() {
        var x = document.forms["checkIn"]["newName"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Tech name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }else{
            checkIn.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```